# C while statement in switch clause

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

This question comes from my C language exam. It asks for the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 4, b = 30;
    printf("%d\n", a);

    switch(a){
        case 1: a = a*10; break;
        case 2: a = a*10; break;
        case 3: a = a*10;
        while (a<b) case 4: {a = a+5;} break; //???
        case 5: a = a*10; break;
        default:
            b = a*10;break;
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

> 4 
>   34

I know the basic idea of while statement and switch statement, but I don't understand what's going on in the fourth line of the switch block.

My guess is that the while condition is tested 7 times until variable a reaches 34 (4<30, 4+5+5+5+5+5+5 = 34). But how about the 'case 4' condition? Shouldn't this condition be tested before adding 5 to variable a? And how about the 'break' after it? I'm totally confused.

Thanks!

Comment: I feel your pain. I've been coding C since 1991 I never had to do such unreadable constructs. This exam is nonsense.

Comment: jumping into the body of a while() loop is a very poor programming practice.  Strongly suggest you never use such a code structure

Answer (score 3):

```
while (a<b) case 4: {a = a+5;} break; //???
```

`case 4` is just a label.

This is equivalent to the below:

```
while (a<b) 
some_label:
{
   a = a+5;
}
break; //This will break out of the surrounding switch.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while (a<b) case 4: {a = a+5;} break;
```

This line of code is within a `switch` statement. The first thing that the `switch` does is to jump to the `case` label `4`.

But this case label is *within a while loop*. At the end of the `a=a+5` instruction, the program goes "back" to the while instruction.

What the program does is performing a `goto` *inside* the `while` loop.

`goto` statements are discouraged, unless when within `switch` blocks with perfectly legible constructs like:

```
  switch(a)
  {
    case 1: a = a*10; break;
    case 2: a = a*10; break;
    case 5: a = a*10; break;
    default:
        b = a*10;break;
}
```

If you're trying to be smart, omitting the `break`, inserting instructions between the `break` and the next `case` ... you have to be aware of what you're doing. And someone else reading the code may have a hard time to interpret it.

That also implies not jumping in the middle of a loop construct or strange things like that.

If you encounter such code in real life, rewrite it. The equivalent would use a `do` ... `while` instruction (the first test is skipped, we can enter the loop even if `a<b`:

```
case 4: do {a = a+5;} while (a<b); break;
```

You get the same result with this code, except that it compiles without warnings and everyone understands what it does.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, while (a < b) each time it will repeat case 4 and add 5 to a, by the time a is more than 30, it will break out of the while loop and switch scope. Then it will print the variable which is now equal to 34.